Why are my results different from their PSRR scheme?
Even though I followed every step given in the Analog devices website, the results were still different and I don't know why. Can anyone give me a solution?
Here is my result:

But their PSRR stimulation diagram:

Here is their website link: https://www.analog.com/en/resources/technical-articles/how-to-get-the-best-results-using-ltspice-part-1.html
Here is my circuit: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1G82G3RealYT8eGNVJaQHlP6DOdQ9vp-a

Uhhhhh....your frequency range is different....

The PSRR plots look the same, your frequency range is, as already stated above, different.
